# Oracle insert select gives not a GROUP BY expression

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

Edit: database version is Oracle 12c

I have two tables,SRC and DEST, and I would like to count the records per id in SRC and insert the result to DEST.

The tables are created with the following script:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE "ID_SEQ" INCREMENT BY 1 MAXVALUE 99999 MINVALUE 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER NOCYCLE;

CREATE TABLE "SRC_TABLE"
(
    "S_ID" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL,
    "SEQ" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL,
    "VALUE" VARCHAR2(1) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE "DEST_TABLE"
(
    "D_ID" NUMBER(10,0) DEFAULT ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL NOT NULL,
    "S_ID" NUMBER(10,0),
    "CNT" VARCHAR2(1) NOT NULL,
    "PROCESS_PROG" VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO SRC_TABLE VALUES (1, 1, '1');
INSERT INTO SRC_TABLE VALUES (1, 2, '1');
INSERT INTO SRC_TABLE VALUES (1, 3, '1');
INSERT INTO SRC_TABLE VALUES (2, 1, '2');
INSERT INTO SRC_TABLE VALUES (2, 2, '2');
INSERT INTO SRC_TABLE VALUES (2, 3, '2');
```

When I execute the following script it caused the "ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression" error:

```
DECLARE
    PROG_NAME VARCHAR2(50) := 'DEMO';
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO DEST_TABLE (S_ID, CNT, PROCESS_PROG)
    SELECT S_ID, COUNT(*), PROG_NAME FROM SRC_TABLE
    GROUP BY S_ID;
END;
```

After some testing, I found that if I replace PROG_NAME with a string then the script worked.

```
DECLARE
    PROG_NAME VARCHAR2(50) := 'DEMO';
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO DEST_TABLE (S_ID, CNT, PROCESS_PROG)
    SELECT S_ID, COUNT(*), 'DEMO' FROM SRC_TABLE
    GROUP BY S_ID;
END;
```

Or, if I explicitly select the value for the D_ID column instead of relying on the DEFAULT value, it also worked:

```
DECLARE
    PROG_NAME VARCHAR2(50) := 'DEMO';
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO DEST_TABLE (D_ID, S_ID, CNT, PROCESS_PROG)
    SELECT ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, TMP.* FROM (
        SELECT S_ID, COUNT(*), PROG_NAME FROM SRC_TABLE
        GROUP BY S_ID
    ) TMP;
END;
```

I have no idea why the first script failed but the other two worked. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is statement that failed (according to what you said):

```
SELECT S_ID, COUNT(*), PROG_NAME FROM SRC_TABLE
GROUP BY S_ID;
```

When there's an aggregation in a query - `count(*)` in your example - then all other columns contained in the `select` column list that aren't aggregated have to be contained in the `group by` clause.

That column is `S_ID`; `PROG_NAME` is a local variable and doesn't have to be put into the `group by` clause.

So, why did your code fail? No idea, because it works just fine for me:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2      PROG_NAME VARCHAR2(50) := 'DEMO';
  3  BEGIN
  4      INSERT INTO DEST_TABLE (S_ID, CNT, PROCESS_PROG)
  5      SELECT S_ID, COUNT(*), PROG_NAME FROM SRC_TABLE
  6      GROUP BY S_ID;
  7  END;
  8  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from dest_table;

      D_ID       S_ID C PROCESS_PROG
---------- ---------- - ----------------------------------------
         1          1 3 DEMO
         2          2 3 DEMO

SQL>
```

Are you **sure** it failed? Could you demonstrate it by posting your own SQL*Plus session (just like I did)?

Comment: Interesting. This fails in Oracle 18 in db<>fiddle though: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9335b1bb39d5338532b62c92190c24bb

Comment: A weird thing is that the error disappears if I comment out the `DEFAUT  ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL` clause on column `D_ID` in `DEST_TABLE`...: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=18b3a08539e6e558dc101fd7157b4f3a

Comment: @GMB: as it won't work in 11g, I used a database trigger instead. Maybe it is the DEFAULT column value, then, but - why? What does it have to do with GROUP BY?

Comment: Exactly: why ?! Doesn't make sense whatsoever.